# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: qgis, icon, memory-layer

I have just used the `shape tool` to create an elliptical buffer around a point. However after doing this, within my layers table I have the symbol seen within the figure below (seen in red box). Note, non of my other layers have any symbol next to them. Does anyone know what the symbol is and what does it mean? I ask this because when I use the `Identify feature symbol` it will only highlight the new elliptical buffer I just made and wont let me click on anything else.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a temporary (in memory) layer. You will have to save it do disk if you want to keep it.

Comment: perfect, I have done this and the symbol is gone, however I am still unable to use the identify feature symbol.

Comment: Have you activated the layer by clicking on it in table of contents?

Comment: Yes, Im very confused as to why it isn't working. Im sure its an issue with my computer rather than the software. Was just asking incase it was a software issue

Comment: Is the `identify feature` symbol greyed out, or do you get no result when clicking the new layer?

Comment: I get no result when clicking the new layer. The symbol is not greyed out.

Comment: Have you marked the new layer? If yes, your features seem to be "empty". Meaning, somehow QGis displays the feature, but you can't buffer it e.g.

Comment: (Noting the discussion above, I've turned the first comment into an answer. You already know this, but it enables the question to be marked as answered.)

Comment: On your wider issues (beyond the question asked) are you fully familiar with the normal operation of the identify tool? You need to understand how to ensure it identifies data from one particular layer or another - see here: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=identify#identify

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I am looking at the link now @Rostranimin to fully understand it

Comment: Great. There are several things to ensure you understood. 1) the identify tool needs to understand what layer to act on. 2) How this works depends on some settings (designed to help with handling overlapping/close features. 3) Depending on the settings it may identify only features from the layer selected in the layers panel OR it may work from top down OR it may give you chance to choose. Another setting changes whether a form opens automatically or not. My guess is that you forgot to select the layer you want to work on in the layers panel. Persist with this initial learning; it gets easier!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This indicates that the layer is in memory only (called a 'scratch layer') and will be lost when closing the QGIS project (without an additional warning as far as I remember) - unless you save the data to a proper file.

Comment: unless you have added the Memory Layer Saver plugin